# The program '[4432] iisexpress.exe' has exited with code -2147023895 (0x800703e9)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2013, .net-4.5, iis-express

I have very frustrating issue with IIS Express. When I start debug everything is ok, but after few requests IIS hangs and crashes. My browser (Chrome Version 37.0.2062.120 m) waits for the response several seconds and then IIS Express stops running. My output is

```
The program '[4432] iisexpress.exe' has exited with code -2147023895 (0x800703e9).
```

and event log looks like this:

```
Log Name:      Application
Source:        Application Error
Date:          2014-09-18 14:12:24
Event ID:      1000
Task Category: (100)
Level:         Error
Keywords:      Classic
User:          N/A
Computer:      COMP0008
Description:
Faulting application name: iisexpress.exe, version: 8.5.9748.0, time stamp: 0x5384d451
Faulting module name: clr.dll, version: 4.0.30319.34014, time stamp: 0x52e0b784
Exception code: 0xc00000fd
Fault offset: 0x000114a7
Faulting process id: 0x15f0
Faulting application start time: 0x01cfd3312b227e51
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\iisexpress.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
Report Id: 0bd590d7-3f2d-11e4-82a5-7845c406525d
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID: 
Event Xml:
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="Application Error" />
    <EventID Qualifiers="0">1000</EventID>
    <Level>2</Level>
    <Task>100</Task>
    <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2014-09-18T12:12:24.000000000Z" />
    <EventRecordID>62449</EventRecordID>
    <Channel>Application</Channel>
    <Computer>COMP0008</Computer>
    <Security />
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Data>iisexpress.exe</Data>
    <Data>8.5.9748.0</Data>
    <Data>5384d451</Data>
    <Data>clr.dll</Data>
    <Data>4.0.30319.34014</Data>
    <Data>52e0b784</Data>
    <Data>c00000fd</Data>
    <Data>000114a7</Data>
    <Data>15f0</Data>
    <Data>01cfd3312b227e51</Data>
    <Data>C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\iisexpress.exe</Data>
    <Data>C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll</Data>
    <Data>0bd590d7-3f2d-11e4-82a5-7845c406525d</Data>
    <Data>
    </Data>
    <Data>
    </Data>
  </EventData>
</Event>
```

I have uninstalled all extensions in my Visual Studio 2013;
Cleared those folders:

```
Documents\IISExpress
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files
```

Still no success. My system: Windows 8.1 with all updates installed.

Any ideas?

EDIT:
I have also disabled Browser Link.

EDIT:
I have cleared

```
%HOMEPATH%\AppData\Local\Temp\iisexpress
```

and reinstalled IIS Express 8.  No change.
I have noticed that if I close browser when it waits for the response nothing happens, but then if I stop or restart debug session, I get this:

[image]

But when I wait several seconds, IIS crashes silently.

Comment: I'd hedge my bet on an overflow or out of memory exception. Are there any background threads? Caching?

Comment: What kind of caching do you mean? My iisexpress.exe has 34 threads for now (7 managed) and its private working set is 158980K only.

Comment: Did you get answer for your question?  I have this problem too.

Comment: Not really, but now it happens very rarely

Comment: Not sure of this, But changing the port number in your web project properties resolved my similar issue.

Comment: I'm with Steven V. 0xc00000fd indicates a stack overflow.

Answer (score 9):

Windows error codes can be cryptic but easily understood with a simple process

1. From the error code `0x800703e9`, take the last 4 characters `03e9`
2. Using a [Hexadecimal to Decimal Converter](http://www.binaryhexconverter.com/hex-to-decimal-converter), convert `03e9` to its decimal counterpart, which in this case is `1001`
3. Using cmd, type `net helpmsg 1001` or whatever decimal value is returned.
4. A more friendly error message will usually appear... providing the original error code starts with 8007 which generally indicates it originated from Windows... or if no message appears then it probably didn't originate from a valid Win32 process.

In this instance, the error you received is `Recursion too deep; the stack overflowed.`