# The program '[7532] iisexpress.exe' has exited with code -2147023895 in VS 2017 on debugging

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2017, iis-express, visual-studio-debugging

I am trying to run a project in Visual Studio Pro 2017 15.9.11

The solution compiles but when I try to debug the IIS throws plenty of errors and stops debugger:

```
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\mscorlib\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.Web\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Web.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Core\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Core.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.ApplicationServices\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.ApplicationServices.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Configuration\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Configuration.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Domain 2): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\mscorlib\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-132062842111632840): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.Web\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Web.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-132062842111632840): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-132062842111632840): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Core\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Core.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-132062842111632840): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.ApplicationServices\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.ApplicationServices.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-132062842111632840): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Configuration\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Configuration.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-132062842111632840): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-132062842111632840): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Runtime.Caching\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Runtime.Caching.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Runtime.Caching\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Runtime.Caching.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-132062842111632840): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.Build.Utilities.v4.0\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.Build.Utilities.v4.0.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.Build.Utilities.v4.0\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.Build.Utilities.v4.0.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-132062842111632840): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.JScript\v4.0_10.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.JScript.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-132062842111632840): Loaded 'C:\Users\cheyenne\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\2a4e7475\222da4d\assembly\dl3\2e2f8301\9addabdb_b328d401\System.Web.Mvc.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-132062842111632840): Loaded 'C:\Users\cheyenne\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\2a4e7475\222da4d\assembly\dl3\f7fdc264\003fe22c_feb1d201\Umbraco.ModelsBuilder.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-132062842111632840): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.PageInspector.Loader\v4.0_1.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.PageInspector.Loader.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-132062842111632840): Loaded 'C:\Users\cheyenne\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\2a4e7475\222da4d\assembly\dl3\7c8700d8\1f4fffdb_b328d401\Microsoft.Web.Helpers.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-132062842111632840): Loaded 'C:\Users\cheyenne\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\2a4e7475\222da4d\assembly\dl3\499e036a\0077b0e3_f3c2d201\Umbraco.Core.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-132062842111632840): Loaded 'C:\Users\cheyenne\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\2a4e7475\222da4d\assembly\dl3\ed77fa42\000e9c93_3d27cf01\System.Web.Optimization.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-132062842111632840): Loaded 'C:\Users\cheyenne\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\2a4e7475\222da4d\assembly\dl3\20370baa\900e80dc_b328d401\System.Web.WebPages.Razor.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-132062842111632840): Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Web Tools\Page Inspector\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.PageInspector.Runtime.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-132062842111632840): Loaded 'C:\Users\cheyenne\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\2a4e7475\222da4d\assembly\dl3\fbaa3625\3271dcda_b328d401\System.Web.Razor.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-132062842111632840): Loaded 'Anonymously Hosted DynamicMethods Assembly'. 
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-132062842111632840): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Numerics\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Numerics.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-132062842111632840): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.Data.OracleClient\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.OracleClient.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-132062842111632840): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.Transactions\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Transactions.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-132062842111632840): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.EnterpriseServices\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.EnterpriseServices.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-132062842111632840): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.EnterpriseServices\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.EnterpriseServices.Wrapper.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-132062842111632840): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Drawing\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Drawing.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-132062842111632840): Loaded 'C:\Users\cheyenne\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\2a4e7475\222da4d\assembly\dl3\92cbb138\00f89c16_2137d201\System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-132062842111632840): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Threading.Tasks\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Threading.Tasks.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-132062842111632840): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Diagnostics.Tracing\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Diagnostics.Tracing.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-132062842111632840): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Collections\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Collections.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-132062842111632840): Loaded 'C:\Users\cheyenne\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\2a4e7475\222da4d\assembly\dl3\fcb5b8ed\0077b0e3_f3c2d201\UmbracoExamine.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-132062842111632840): Loaded 'C:\Users\cheyenne\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\2a4e7475\222da4d\assembly\dl3\03dd5a4d\838087d9_b328d401\Lucene.Net.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-132062842111632840): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Threading\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Threading.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-132062842111632840): Loaded 'C:\Users\cheyenne\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\2a4e7475\222da4d\assembly\dl3\c924b574\8ae384b2_091ed401\Jumoo.uSync.Core.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-132062842111632840): Loaded 'Microsoft.GeneratedCode'. 
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-132062842111632840): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.CSharp\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.CSharp.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-132062842111632840): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.Services\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Web.Services.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-132062842111632840): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.IdentityModel\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.IdentityModel.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-132062842111632840): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.ServiceModel.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-132062842111632840): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel.Web\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.ServiceModel.Web.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-132062842111632840): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Activities\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Activities.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-132062842111632840): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel.Activities\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.ServiceModel.Activities.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-132062842111632840): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.WorkflowServices\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.WorkflowServices.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-132062842111632840): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Data.DataSetExtensions\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-132062842111632840): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.DynamicData\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.DynamicData.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-132062842111632840): Loaded 'C:\Users\cheyenne\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\2a4e7475\222da4d\assembly\dl3\013046ba\00866eb6_d810ce01\Antlr3.Runtime.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-132062842111632840): Loaded 'C:\Users\cheyenne\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\2a4e7475\222da4d\assembly\dl3\b0ad3403\d881c2cf_b328d401\ClientDependency.Core.Mvc.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-132062842111632840): Loaded 'C:\Users\cheyenne\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\2a4e7475\222da4d\assembly\dl3\15ef9f85\0077b0e3_f3c2d201\controls.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-132062842111632840): Loaded 'C:\Users\cheyenne\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\2a4e7475\222da4d\assembly\dl3\2963df67\34173c20_b428d401\CookComputing.XmlRpcV2.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-132062842111632840): Loaded 'C:\Users\cheyenne\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\2a4e7475\222da4d\assembly\dl3\fdeabb40\20aa87a3_102ed501\MyNamespace.Notification.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-132062842111632840): Loaded 'C:\Users\cheyenne\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\2a4e7475\222da4d\assembly\dl3\59e04176\4d8bce3c_1d2ed501\MyNamespace.Repositories.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-132062842111632840): Loaded 'C:\Users\cheyenne\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\2a4e7475\222da4d\assembly\dl3\b33422e5\6fbbdba3_102ed501\MyNamespace.Umbraco.Mappers.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-132062842111632840): Loaded 'C:\Users\cheyenne\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\2a4e7475\222da4d\assembly\dl3\bbdbd6b0\003e06a9_b6ddd101\HtmlAgilityPack.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-132062842111632840): Loaded 'C:\Users\cheyenne\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\2a4e7475\222da4d\assembly\dl3\89e61e00\b524c0e7_b328d401\ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-132062842111632840): Loaded 'C:\Users\cheyenne\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\2a4e7475\222da4d\assembly\dl3\85227878\005ef209_1ba7d201\ImageProcessor.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-132062842111632840): Loaded 'C:\Users\cheyenne\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\2a4e7475\222da4d\assembly\dl3\7334088a\006b77c9_83a1d201\itextsharp.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-132062842111632840): Loaded 'C:\Users\cheyenne\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\2a4e7475\222da4d\assembly\dl3\f47275c4\006b77c9_83a1d201\itextsharp.xmlworker.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-132062842111632840): Loaded 'C:\Users\cheyenne\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\2a4e7475\222da4d\assembly\dl3\7d115f4b\0039cf43_30d3d101\MarkdownSharp.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-132062842111632840): Loaded 'C:\Users\cheyenne\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\2a4e7475\222da4d\assembly\dl3\ea826ff8\0077b0e3_f3c2d201\Microsoft.ApplicationBlocks.Data.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-132062842111632840): Loaded 'C:\Users\cheyenne\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\2a4e7475\222da4d\assembly\dl3\999ec8b8\01fa3fd9_b328d401\Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-132062842111632840): Loaded 'C:\Users\cheyenne\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\2a4e7475\222da4d\assembly\dl3\bd562a0c\000f3ffa_6fddd101\Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Core.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-132062842111632840): Loaded 'C:\Users\cheyenne\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\2a4e7475\222da4d\assembly\dl3\cb61b080\0021b291_fba9d001\Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-132062842111632840): Loaded 'C:\Users\cheyenne\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\2a4e7475\222da4d\assembly\dl3\c5a790bd\001be821_1f56d201\Microsoft.IO.RecyclableMemoryStream.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-132062842111632840): Loaded 'C:\Users\cheyenne\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\2a4e7475\222da4d\assembly\dl3\04ebd124\94b2d4e0_b328d401\Microsoft.Owin.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-132062842111632840): Loaded 'C:\Users\cheyenne\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\2a4e7475\222da4d\assembly\dl3\0b8e3946\78eceee0_b328d401\Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-132062842111632840): Loaded 'C:\Users\cheyenne\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\2a4e7475\222da4d\assembly\dl3\977fdbed\448ccde0_b328d401\Microsoft.Owin.Security.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-132062842111632840): Loaded 'C:\Users\cheyenne\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\2a4e7475\222da4d\assembly\dl3\96e20b6c\00bf504c_8f47d001\Microsoft.Owin.Security.Facebook.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-132062842111632840): Loaded 'C:\Users\cheyenne\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\2a4e7475\222da4d\assembly\dl3\a8beb17b\546204e1_b328d401\Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-132062842111632840): Loaded 'C:\Users\cheyenne\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\2a4e7475\222da4d\assembly\dl3\cf4af1a6\f545f7e4_b328d401\MySql.Data.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-132062842111632840): Loaded 'C:\Users\cheyenne\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\2a4e7475\222da4d\assembly\dl3\71b72f8f\fd08c1e6_b328d401\Owin.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-132062842111632840): Loaded 'C:\Users\cheyenne\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\2a4e7475\222da4d\assembly\dl3\d4d86670\00b10a32_bbe6d201\RazorEngine.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-132062842111632840): Loaded 'C:\Users\cheyenne\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\2a4e7475\222da4d\assembly\dl3\d90e9d5c\0077b0e3_f3c2d201\SQLCE4Umbraco.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-132062842111632840): Loaded 'C:\Users\cheyenne\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\2a4e7475\222da4d\assembly\dl3\1184fd66\0086ec3f_e888d001\System.Collections.Immutable.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-132062842111632840): Loaded 'C:\Users\cheyenne\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\2a4e7475\222da4d\assembly\dl3\716732b7\0077b0e3_f3c2d201\System.Data.SqlServerCe.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-132062842111632840): Loaded 'C:\Users\cheyenne\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\2a4e7475\222da4d\assembly\dl3\d695b21f\0077b0e3_f3c2d201\System.Data.SqlServerCe.Entity.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-132062842111632840): Loaded 'C:\Users\cheyenne\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\2a4e7475\222da4d\assembly\dl3\92a21d09\383976df_b328d401\System.Net.Http.Extensions.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-132062842111632840): Loaded 'C:\Users\cheyenne\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\2a4e7475\222da4d\assembly\dl3\3539cd0b\c6e986df_b328d401\System.Net.Http.Primitives.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-132062842111632840): Loaded 'C:\Users\cheyenne\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\2a4e7475\222da4d\assembly\dl3\3f09b333\001623ba_8d89d001\System.Reflection.Metadata.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-132062842111632840): Loaded 'C:\Users\cheyenne\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\2a4e7475\222da4d\assembly\dl3\921d4f49\4e5e6fdc_b328d401\System.Web.Helpers.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Numerics\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Numerics.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-132062842111632840): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Data.Linq\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.Linq.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-132062842111632840): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.Mobile\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Web.Mobile.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-132062842111632840): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.RegularExpressions\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Web.RegularExpressions.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.RegularExpressions\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Web.RegularExpressions.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-132062842111632840): Loaded 'C:\Users\cheyenne\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\2a4e7475\222da4d\App_Web_fanoe.cshtml.8bbe1d5f._0c6_kif.dll'. 
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-132062842111632840): Loaded 'C:\Users\cheyenne\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\2a4e7475\222da4d\App_Web_base.cshtml.353447c8.akvb2knh.dll'. 
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-132062842111632840): Loaded 'C:\Users\cheyenne\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\2a4e7475\222da4d\App_Web_macro.cshtml.353447c8.rfxwch8w.dll'. 
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-132062842111632840): Loaded 'C:\Users\cheyenne\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\2a4e7475\222da4d\App_Web_relatedcontent.cshtml.d673bf47.iiw1avrv.dll'. 
The program '[11280] iisexpress.exe' has exited with code -2147023895 (0x800703e9).
```

I listed above only half of errors as the description couldn't contain all of them here.

I had no errors, of warnings the only one worrying is Microsoft.CSharp.Analyzer thrown an exception

Since then I deleted my .vs file and now no errors, no warnings whatsoever.

All projects are .NET 4.5, there is no version conflict. There is no namespace conflict either anywhere.

Comment: # for hex 0x800703e9 / decimal -2147023895 :
  COR_E_STACKOVERFLOW                                           corerror.h
# MessageText:
# Is raised by the EE when the execution stack overflows as
# it is attempting to ex
# 1 matches found for "800703e9"

Comment: The error message indicates a stack overflow, see [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25913092/the-program-4432-iisexpress-exe-has-exited-with-code-2147023895-0x800703e9). So for `Recursion too deep; the stack overflowed`, maybe this issue results from the code but not related  vs settings.

Comment: Yes, it was Stack overflow exception